# Binary Tree operator overloading and recursion

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to overload the == operator for a binary tree to compare if two trees have identical data at same nodes.  So far this is what I have:

```
bool TreeType::operator==(const TreeType& otherTree) const
{
    if((root == NULL) && (otherTree.root == NULL))
        return true; //two null trees are equal
    else if((root != NULL) && (otherTree.root != NULL))
    {
        return((root->info == otherTree.root->info) &&
               //this part doesn't actually do anything recursively...
               //(root->left == otherTree.root->left) &&
               //(root->right == otherTree.root->right))
    }
    else
        return false; //one tree is null the other is not
}


//TREETYPE DECLARATIONS
struct TreeNode;
enum OrderType {PRE_ORDER, IN_ORDER, POST_ORDER};
class TreeType
{
public:
  TreeType();                     // constructor
 ~TreeType();                    // destructor
  TreeType(const TreeType& originalTree); 
  void operator=(const TreeType& originalTree);
  // copy constructor
  void MakeEmpty();
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool IsFull() const;
  int LengthIs() const; 
  void RetrieveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found);
  void InsertItem(ItemType item);
  void DeleteItem(ItemType item);
  void ResetTree(OrderType order); 
  void GetNextItem (ItemType& item, OrderType order, 
       bool& finished);
  void Print(std::ofstream& outFile) const;
  bool operator==(const TreeType&) const;
private:
  TreeNode* root;
  QueType preQue;
  QueType inQue;
  QueType postQue;
};


//DEFINITIONS
struct TreeNode
{
  ItemType info;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;
};

bool TreeType::IsFull() const
// Returns true if there is no room for another item 
//  on the free store; false otherwise.
{
  TreeNode* location;
  try
  {
    location = new TreeNode;
    delete location;
    return false;
  }
  catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
  {
    return true;
  }
}

bool TreeType::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if the tree is empty; false otherwise.
{
  return root == NULL;
}

int CountNodes(TreeNode* tree);

int TreeType::LengthIs() const
// Calls recursive function CountNodes to count the 
// nodes in the tree.
{
  return CountNodes(root);
}


int CountNodes(TreeNode* tree)
// Post: returns the number of nodes in the tree.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
    return 0;
  else 
    return CountNodes(tree->left) + CountNodes(tree->right) + 1;
}

void Retrieve(TreeNode* tree, 
     ItemType& item, bool& found);

void TreeType::RetrieveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found)
// Calls recursive function Retrieve to search the tree for item.
{
  Retrieve(root, item, found);
}


void Retrieve(TreeNode* tree, 
     ItemType& item, bool& found)
// Recursively searches tree for item.
// Post: If there is an element someItem whose key matches item's,
//       found is true and item is set to a copy of someItem; 
//       otherwise found is false and item is unchanged.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
    found = false;                     // item is not found.
  else if (item info)      
    Retrieve(tree->left, item, found); // Search left subtree.
  else if (item > tree->info)
    Retrieve(tree->right, item, found);// Search right subtree.
  else
  {
    item = tree->info;                 // item is found.
    found = true;
   }
} 

void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item);

void TreeType::InsertItem(ItemType item)
// Calls recursive function Insert to insert item into tree.
{
  Insert(root, item);
}


void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item)
// Inserts item into tree.
// Post:  item is in tree; search property is maintained.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
  {// Insertion place found.
    tree = new TreeNode;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->info = item;
  }
  else if (item info)
    Insert(tree->left, item);    // Insert in left subtree.
  else
    Insert(tree->right, item);   // Insert in right subtree.
} 
void DeleteNode(TreeNode*& tree);

void Delete(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item);

void TreeType::DeleteItem(ItemType item)
// Calls recursive function Delete to delete item from tree.
{
  Delete(root, item);
}


void Delete(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item)
// Deletes item from tree.
// Post:  item is not in tree.
{
  if (item info)
    Delete(tree->left, item);   // Look in left subtree.
  else if (item > tree->info)
    Delete(tree->right, item);  // Look in right subtree.
  else
    DeleteNode(tree);           // Node found; call DeleteNode.
}   

void GetPredecessor(TreeNode* tree, ItemType& data);

void DeleteNode(TreeNode*& tree)
// Deletes the node pointed to by tree.
// Post: The user's data in the node pointed to by tree is no 
//       longer in the tree.  If tree is a leaf node or has only 
//       non-NULL child pointer the node pointed to by tree is 
//       deleted; otherwise, the user's data is replaced by its 
//       logical predecessor and the predecessor's node is deleted.
{
  ItemType data;
  TreeNode* tempPtr;

  tempPtr = tree;
  if (tree->left == NULL)
  {
    tree = tree->right;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  else if (tree->right == NULL)
  {
    tree = tree->left;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  else
  {
    GetPredecessor(tree->left, data);
    tree->info = data;
    Delete(tree->left, data);  // Delete predecessor node.
  }
}

void GetPredecessor(TreeNode* tree, ItemType& data)
// Sets data to the info member of the right-most node in tree.
{
  while (tree->right != NULL)
    tree = tree->right;
  data = tree->info;
}

void PrintTree(TreeNode* tree, std::ofstream& outFile) 
// Prints info member of items in tree in sorted order on outFile.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    PrintTree(tree->left, outFile);   // Print left subtree.
    outFile info;
    PrintTree(tree->right, outFile);  // Print right subtree.
  }
}

void TreeType::Print(std::ofstream& outFile) const
// Calls recursive function Print to print items in the tree.
{
  PrintTree(root, outFile);
}

TreeType::TreeType()
{
  root = NULL;
}

void Destroy(TreeNode*& tree);

TreeType::~TreeType()
// Calls recursive function Destroy to destroy the tree.
{
  Destroy(root);
}


void Destroy(TreeNode*& tree)
// Post: tree is empty; nodes have been deallocated.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    Destroy(tree->left);
    Destroy(tree->right);
    delete tree;
  }
}

void TreeType::MakeEmpty()
{
  Destroy(root);
  root = NULL;
}


void CopyTree(TreeNode*& copy, 
     const TreeNode* originalTree);

TreeType::TreeType(const TreeType& originalTree)
// Calls recursive function CopyTree to copy originalTree 
//  into root.
{
  CopyTree(root, originalTree.root);
}

void TreeType::operator= 
     (const TreeType& originalTree)
// Calls recursive function CopyTree to copy originalTree 
// into root.
{
  {
  if (&originalTree == this)
    return;             // Ignore assigning self to self
  Destroy(root);      // Deallocate existing tree nodes
  CopyTree(root, originalTree.root);
  }

}
void CopyTree(TreeNode*& copy, 
     const TreeNode* originalTree)
// Post: copy is the root of a tree that is a duplicate 
//       of originalTree.
{
  if (originalTree == NULL)
    copy = NULL;
  else
  {
    copy = new TreeNode;
    copy->info = originalTree->info;
    CopyTree(copy->left, originalTree->left);
    CopyTree(copy->right, originalTree->right);
  }
}
// Function prototypes for auxiliary functions.

void PreOrder(TreeNode*, QueType&);
// Enqueues tree items in preorder.


void InOrder(TreeNode*, QueType&);
// Enqueues tree items in inorder.


void PostOrder(TreeNode*, QueType&);
// Enqueues tree items in postorder.


void TreeType::ResetTree(OrderType order)
// Calls function to create a queue of the tree elements in 
// the desired order.
{
  switch (order)
  {
    case PRE_ORDER : PreOrder(root, preQue);
                     break;
    case IN_ORDER  : InOrder(root, inQue);
                     break;
    case POST_ORDER: PostOrder(root, postQue);
                     break;
  }
}


void PreOrder(TreeNode* tree, 
     QueType& preQue)
// Post: preQue contains the tree items in preorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    preQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
    PreOrder(tree->left, preQue);
    PreOrder(tree->right, preQue);
  }
}


void InOrder(TreeNode* tree, 
     QueType& inQue)
// Post: inQue contains the tree items in inorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    InOrder(tree->left, inQue);
    inQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
    InOrder(tree->right, inQue);
  }
}


void PostOrder(TreeNode* tree, 
     QueType& postQue)
// Post: postQue contains the tree items in postorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    PostOrder(tree->left, postQue);
    PostOrder(tree->right, postQue);
    postQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
  }
}


void TreeType::GetNextItem(ItemType& item, 
     OrderType order, bool& finished)
// Returns the next item in the desired order.
// Post: For the desired order, item is the next item in the queue.
//       If item is the last one in the queue, finished is true; 
//       otherwise finished is false.
{
  finished = false;
  switch (order)
  {
    case PRE_ORDER  : preQue.Dequeue(item);
                      if (preQue.IsEmpty())
                        finished = true;
                      break;
    case IN_ORDER   : inQue.Dequeue(item);
                      if (inQue.IsEmpty())
                        finished = true;
                      break;
    case  POST_ORDER: postQue.Dequeue(item);
                      if (postQue.IsEmpty())
                        finished = true;
                      break;
  }
}
```

I have a similar function that takes two TreeNode pointers as parameters but I've been stuck on how to convert it to this function.

The definition of tree is from a book.  I'm just supposed to add the functionality of an overloaded == operator.

Comment: Could you show the definition of `TreeType` ? This would help. Also, it is weird that you can have a "null" node instance (an instance with `root` set to `null`): it's like you have two ways of representing an empty node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to add equality operator to the `node` class.

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node * left;
    node * right;

    friend bool operator==(node const & lhs, node const & rhs)
    {
        return lhs.info == rhs.info
            && ((lhs.left == 0 && rhs.left == 0)
                || (lhs.left != 0 && rhs.left != 0 && *lhs.left == *rhs.left))
            && ((lhs.right == 0 && rhs.right == 0)
                || (lhs.right != 0 && rhs.right != 0 && *lhs.right == *rhs.right));
    }
};
```

Then you can simply compare root nodes from `TreeType::operator==`.

```
bool TreeType::operator==(const TreeType& otherTree) const
{
    return (root == 0 && otherTree.root == 0)
        || (root != 0 && otherTree.root != 0 && *root == *otherTree.root);
}
```

Comment: +1, but since you have implemented the node as a struct (all fields public) the free function `operator==` need not be friend.

Comment: yeah I already have this implementation, but I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to make it part of the TreeType class.

Comment: +1 to the solution above. What do you mean you are supposed to make it part of the TreeType class? If you meant that you should be able to compare two TreeType, then the above still works. Just need to add bool operator==(const TreeType&) that utilize node#operator== to compare the root node.

Comment: @furious.snail, I don't understand the restriction, but the solution remains the same; just rename `operator==` to `compare_nodes` and move it from `node` to `TreeType`.

Comment: That makes sense.  The assignment is to overload the == operator but I can just call this function in that definition.

Comment: @dribeas, putting operators inside the class definition is a standard idiom and it has slightly different semantics than defining it outside the class (friends defined inside a class definition can only be found through ADL).

Answer (score 0):

Generally the idea in these cases is to have a data structure which is a tree consisting of trees and leaf nodes. Something like

```
struct TreeType
{
    std::vector<TreeType> subtrees;
    std::vector<LeafNodes> leafs;
}
```

This allows one to define a `==` operator along the lines of

```
bool TreeType::operator==(const TreeType& rhs) const
{
    if each subtree == subtree && each leaf == leaf
    then true
    else false
}
```

Here the `subtree` comparison will call the `==` operator recursively on the children trees.

EDIT: It would be handy if you provided the exact organization of your TreeType data structure to allow for a better/specific answer.

Comment: That's a fairly uncommon implementation for a tree... with many data elements attached to each single node.

Comment: I believe I missed the part in the question where it said "binary tree", the implementation I presented was a generic tree with each node having either children nodes or leaf elements connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Given this class:

```
class TreeNode
{
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;
  int value;

  bool operator==(const TreeNode& node);
};
```

I would write the `==` operator like this:

```
bool TreeNode::operator==(const TreeNode& node)
{
  // Are we comparing the node to itself ?
  if (&node == this)
    return true;

  // We have a left node
  if (left != NULL)
  {
     // Does node have a left node too ?
     if (value.left != NULL)
     {
       // Are they different ?
       if (!(*left == *value.left))
         return false;
     } else
       // Node has no left node
       return false;
  } else
  {
    // We don't have a left node, does node have one ?
    if (value.left != NULL)
      return false;
  }

  // We have a right node
  if (right != NULL)
  {
     // Does node have a right node too ?
     if (value.right != NULL)
     {
       // Are they different ?
       if (!(*right == *value.right))
         return false;
     } else
       // Node has no right node
       return false;
  } else
  {
    // We don't have a right node, does node have one ?
    if (value.right != NULL)
      return false;
  }

  // Return true only if we have the same value.
  return (value == node.value);
}
```

Of course the recursion "end-conditions" can be switched for the algorithm to be optimized (checking the `value`s first might be more efficient).

This is left to you as an exercise :D

Answer (score 0):

```
//value is an integer not an object so that will give you syntax errors.
//This is a more correct way to write this
bool TreeNode::operator==(const TreeNode& node)
{
     if (&node == this) return true;
     if (left != NULL)
     {
         if (node.left != NULL) if (*left != *node.left) return false;
         else return false;
     }
     else if (node.left != NULL) return false;
     if (right != NULL)
     {
         if (node.right != NULL) if (*right != *node.right) return false;
         else return false;
     }
     else if (node.right != NULL) return false;
     return (value == node.value);
}
```